# Is there a way to implement `Comparable<T>` with delegation?

Tags: kotlin

What I want:

`data class Customer (val id: Int) : Comparable by id`

But comparable requires a type param, which means it then can't delegate to `id`. Is this doable? Or am I just missing some reason this idea doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [comparingInt](https://medium.com/@appmattus/effective-kotlin-item-14-consider-implementing-comparable-4dda1c6e92a8) for `val id`, example:

> ```
> class Date(val year: Int, val month: Int, val day: Int) :
>     Comparable<Date> {    
>     override fun compareTo(other: Date): Int {
>         return COMPARATOR.compare(this, other)
>     }    
>     companion object {
>         private val COMPARATOR =
>             Comparator.comparingInt<Date> { it.year }
>                 .thenComparingInt { it.month }
>                 .thenComparingInt { it.day }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I did something similar where I used `compareTo(this, that, {year}, {month}, {day})`, but I'm really curious if this is doable via delegation :)

Comment: @Rollie but delegation can be to interface without members

Comment: You might consider the more versatile: `private val COMPARATOR = compareBy<Date>( { it.year }, { it.month }, { it.day })` so it doesn't require JDK8.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
data class Customer(val id: Int) : Comparable<Customer> by IntComparator(id, { it.id })

class IntComparator<T>(private val number: Int, private val getter: (T) -> Int) : Comparable<T> {

    override fun compareTo(other: T): Int = this.number.compareTo(getter(other))
}
```

This example needs to be adapted to your most common cases to make it more elegant. You could create Comparators for classes, interfaces, data tuples etc.

Comment: It could look cleaner by using `T.() -> Int` so you can omit the `it`. Might be worth mentioning this would only work for immutable properties. You could also genericize this for any comparable property type: `class ComparableDelegate<T, C: Comparable<C>>(val source: C, val getter: T.() -> C): Comparable<T>`.

Comment: This or just a wrapper around `Comparable` is currently my favorite approach;  `data class Customer(val id: Int) : MyComparable({id})` feels like the most concise, even though I don't love obfuscating the fact that this implements the `Comparable` interface indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a very clean way to do this because referencing `this` (as in the attached object) in the delegate constructor is not supported.

Consider that implementing Comparable using an Int property is really trivial anyway:

```
class Test (val x: Int = 0) : Comparable<Test> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Test) = x - other.x
}
```

or for any property that is Comparable:

```
class Test (val x: Long = 0) : Comparable<Test> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Test) = x.compareTo(other.x)
}
```

Comment: It seems like the compiler may have all the information it needs to solve this - if I say `: Comparable<Customer> by x`, it just needs to view `x` as a member of `Customer`, and then can in the background implement the appropriate `compareTo` method. Not to say this is a priority for the language evolution :)

Answer (score -2):

If a customer is only comparable by its Id, then define the type:

```
data class Customer (val id: Int) : Comparable<Int> by id
```

Comment: I tried this, but it caused issues when trying to sort lists of `Customer` because of the signature of `sortBy`/`sortedBy`